# In facebook FQL filter by created_time on video table doesn't work as expected (i.e. return old results)

Tags: facebook-fql

I have the following query on the video table, and it return old results.

```
SELECT owner, vid FROM video WHERE owner = 123456 AND created_time >  1347789391 
ORDER BY created_time DESC LIMIT 100
```

Similar query on photos perform the filter as expected

```
SELECT owner, caption, FROM photo WHERE aid = 123456 AND created > 1347789391 
ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 100
```

Any ideas?
I looked for known bugs but couldn't find any. My workaround is to check the return results and do the filter my self, but that of course not ideal.